# Is there a way to avoid the outside visibility of template friend declarations?

Tags: c++, templates

Take a look at the following example:

a.h:

```
class A {
protected:
  template<class T>
  friend void b();
};
```

b.h:

```
template<class T>
void b() {}
```

main.cxx:

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
  b<double>();
}
```

Notice that I forgot to include "b.h" in the main file. Unfortunately, the compiler picks up the friend declaration in class A and compiles the main function without complaining. I'm left with a cryptic link error, which is surprising since instantiation should occur in main.cxx:

```
[joel@fedora-joel friend]$ g++ main.cxx 
/tmp/ccfpaeHw.o: In function `main':
main.cxx:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `void b<double>()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My question is: why does the compiler allow this? Is there a way against it?

Comment: By the principle of separate compilation, each translation unit 
(TU) is compiled separately as long as all information necessary for a TU is available at compile time. For a function with the signature of b, it certainly is (after the pre-compiler pasts a.h into main.cpp). Unresolved references are entered into a symbol table, to be resolved by the linker (hence the linker error). I don't see how (or why) to avoid this.

Comment: Why avoid this? Because it's ugly! Mentioning the existence of a function as a friend of a class shouldn't allow outside code to use it, IMHO. I'm sure there are excellent technical reasons for this behavior, but finding a way to make this declaration unavailable to outside code would avoid errors, especially for beginners.

Comment: The 'why' was more a technical point. If you go through the steps a compiler/linker takes, this would be hard to implement (eg, you'd need some cross-TU validity checks). C(++) has traditionally used "separate compilation" which would not be possible then. And yes, I agree, this can lead to hard-to-track errors when debugging.

Comment: This is why you should not declare friendship to something which is defined in a different header. Also `protected:` is meaningless here; friend declarations do not have access specifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO/IEC 14882:2003, §11.4, paragraph 3 says this :

> A function first declared in a friend declaration has external linkage (3.5). Otherwise, the function retains its previous linkage (7.1.1).

So, the friend declaration doubles as a function declaration. This allows `main` to call the function, so there is no compiler error.

The linker error occurs because there is no matching function definition for the declaration.

I don't see a way to avoid this behavior (since the standard prescribes it). It makes sense too, since a function declaration is needed to make the friend declaration valid anyway (otherwise you'd have a friend declaration for an undeclared function). So, if the friend declaration wouldn't double as a function declaration, the function declaration would have to be provided otherwise (by including the appropriate header eg.).

Comment: Thanks for citing the standard, it's always helpful. However, you haven't addressed the second part of my question. I suppose your answer is no?

Comment: @static_rtti : yes - should have added that explicitly - will fix that now.